# ViewPager not swiping on touching child recyclerview, fine otherwise

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, slide

Having an odd issue with a RecyclerView within in a ViewPager. Adapter is a PagerAdapter that has fixed size of two and returns pre-inflated ViewGroups. One of which has a RecyclerView in it.

Cannot get my head around it. Any help would be much appreciated. 
On inflating the view do I ened to set the root? or possibly attachToRoot?

Sliding works fine on all but touching the RecyclerView.

Support version 23.3.0 but was still an issue on previous versions, so don't believe that is it.

---

xml that contains the RecyclerView. The InterceptingLayout is just a RelativeLayout in this case, with option of intercepting touch events, but isn't the issue here.

```
    <xxxx.layouts.InterceptingRelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_interceptor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.malinskiy.superrecyclerview.SuperRecyclerView 
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            app:layout_empty="@layout/layout_empty"
            app:layout_moreProgress="@layout/layout_empty"
            app:mainLayoutId="@layout/recyclerview_list"
            app:recyclerPaddingTop="@dimen/status_bar_toolbar_height"/>

        </xxx.layouts.InterceptingRelativeLayout>
```

---

Inflation of ViewGroup that contains RecyclerView

```
listInterceptor = (getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.stub_list_content, null) as InterceptingRelativeLayout
```

---

And relevant methods in Pager Adapter

```
    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        if (position == 0) {
            container.addView(daypicker)
            return daypicker
        } else {
            container.addView(listInterceptor)
            return listInterceptor
        }

    override fun getItemPosition(obj: Any?) = POSITION_NONE

    override fun getCount() = 2

    override fun isViewFromObject(arg0: View, arg1: Any): Boolean {
        return arg0 === arg1
    }
```